# Can't pull .json content from file using React-native

Tags: json, react-native

I am attempting to pull the contents of this `.json` file `(colors.json)`. I don't really know what the issue is with my code. Can't figure out the correct call in the Text tag

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.39.0
```

## Quote.js

```
var colors = require('./colors.json');

class Quote extends Component {
    render () {
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={[styles.author, styles.text]}>Denise Lee Yohn</Text>
          **<Text style={styles.quote}> {colors.hexValue}</Text>**          
     </View>
    )
   }
}
```

## Colors.json

```
{
    "colorsArray":[{
            "colorName":"red",
            "hexValue":"#f00"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"green",
            "hexValue":"#0f0"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"blue",
            "hexValue":"#00f"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"black",
            "hexValue":"#000"
        }
    ]
}
```

## Image of Output (Edit)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a loop on the colors array in render() method to display each color's `hexValue`.

```
render () {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={[styles.author, styles.text]}>Denise Lee Yohn</Text>
      {
        colors.colorsArray.map((color, index) => {
          return <Text key={index} style={styles.quote}>{color.hexValue}</Text>;
        })
      }        
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to be working. There is nothing being written on the screen at all. Do I need to declare anything before dropping the above code into the file? (I have restarted my server).

Comment: Just replace your render() with the above code and it should be working fine. If it is still not working, can you take a screenshot on what is being shown?

Comment: the screenshot of the output is in the question.

Comment: It also appears that `import colors from './colors.json';` is now the accepted syntax, rather than `var colors = require('./colors.json');`